# How to draw anything in Sage?

Tags: drawing, sage

I took an example from here http://wiki.sagemath.org/pics, entered it, but nothing happened:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a really time-consuming graphics to create!  The many plot points is one reason, not the only one - it took me several minutes to see output just from the first 10 iterations.  Presumably why it was uploaded as a *picture*. If you change it from `(1,20)` to `(1,5)` you can start to see the beginnings of this.  Or, you can just skip the `for` loop and do

```
f = lambda x: sum([sin(x*3^i)/(2^i) for i in range(1,10)])
plot(f,0,float(pi/3),plot_points=2000).show()
```

and wait for that one.

The moral of the story is that everywhere continuous, nowhere differentiable functions are *really* hard to visualize!